# Eliminating blank space when concatenating multiple columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want to create an address column that looks like this:
123 S Main St.

I have 4 columns I am combining:
STNo, PreDir, STName, Suffix

Some addresses don't have a PreDir though, when that happens there is an extra space between the street number and street name. I want to get rid of that space when the PreDir field is empty.

The code I am currently using:

```
select
    [STNo] + ' ' + case
    WHEN [PreDir] = '' then LTRIM([PreDir])
    else [PreDir]
    End + ' ' + [STName] + ' ' + [Suffix] as PropertyAddress
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incorporate the space between `StNo` and `PreDir` into the `CASE` expression when `PreDir` is not empty:

```
select
    [STNo] + case
    WHEN [PreDir] = '' then LTRIM([PreDir])
    else ' ' + [PreDir]
    End + ' ' + [STName] + ' ' + [Suffix] as PropertyAddress
```